# Code to be executed each time a function is called

Tags: javascript

I have written a program with lots of functions and function calls. I would like to be able to call code *just before* every function call. For example, each time a function is called, have the console log

```
console.log("A function has been called!");
```

I would like to write this once and for all, not go through every function declaration. I guess this is similar in spirit to the [CSS pseudo elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) `:before` and `:after`, but applied to function calls in JavaScript.

Comment: Is this just for debugging or do you have some deeper purpose?

Comment: I want to inject 1ms pauses at every function invocation to allow for DOM repaints to happen smoothly.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have a sleep function that would allow you to easily do that; not *every* function would "need" to be changed (only the repainting ones) and finally, this just sounds too hacky - there are more standard ways to solve this king of problem.

Comment: Agreed with @missingno; this sounds like a fairly awful idea. You might make DOM repaints "smoother" but this could very well bring JS execution down to a grinding halt, by adding a 1 ms overhead to every function call.

Comment: To my knowledge, console.log() doesn't free the browser thread from executing Javascript. Instead, you should use setTimeout() in strategic locations to get the desired effect, but definitely not in the beginning of every function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically looking for [Aspect-Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) in JavaScript. See [Javascript AOP libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005486/javascript-aop-libraries).

More questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+aop

Answer (score 3):

I don’t think there’s any built-in way to do something like this. Why not use a JavaScript debugger like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and set breakpoints at the functions you think might be giving you trouble?

Comment: Even if there was a way to do this, I doubt it would be better than a propper debugger.

Comment: Agreed. AFAIK there is no way

Comment: Once you learn working with it, Firebug is a proper debugger.

Comment: @nightcracker; haha, I was talking about the OP's hack.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to automatically inject console spew for every function.  But if you want to be explicit about which functions spew logging to the console, you could likely use a closure.

```
function ConsoleLogWrap(obj, funcname, msg) {
    var xmsg = msg;
    var xfuncname = funcname;
    var xobj = obj;

    obj[funcname+"$"] = obj[funcname];
    obj[funcname] = function () {

        try {
            console.log(xmsg);
        } catch(e) {
        }

        xobj[xfuncname+"$"](arguments);

    };

}


function Addition(x, y) {
   return x + y;
}

ConsoleLogWrap(window, "Addition", "Addition was called");

window.Addition(5,5); // this will spew out "Addition was called" and return the result of 5+5.
```

Comment: What ever I posted originally had plenty of bugs.  The above does work!

Answer (score 1):

You can add methods to every function you create by extending `Function.prototype`.

To make a function run asynchronously as you seem to indicate in your comment, you could add a function like this:

```
Function.prototype.makeAsync = function() {
    var func = this;
    var args = arguments;
    setTimeout(function() {
        func.call.apply( func, args );
    }, 1 );
};
```

...then invoke it like this:

```
function my_func( a, b, c ) {
    console.log( this );
    console.log( a, b, c );
}

my_func.makeAsync( element, 1, 2, 3 );
```

Note that the first argument you pass to `makeAsync` becomes the `this` value of the function you're invoking.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/3kuad/

Answer (score -1):

I've never seen anyone do this before, so I'm assuming it's not possible.

I did a quick google search and nothing useful came back. Just inheritance, but I don't see how that's particularly helpful.

**Looks like bdesham beat me to it!**