# Any way to add code to every function call

Tags: javascript

I'd like a quick way to add something like

```
console.log(functionName)
```

to the top of every function.

Is there a quick and easy way to do this, or would I need to manually add that code to every function.

Comment: Depends; if your code is formatted consistently, you could probably use an editor regex.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code to be executed each time a function is called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489346/code-to-be-executed-each-time-a-function-is-called)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
for( var x in window) {
    if( typeof window[x] == "function") {
        (function(x) {
            var ox = window[x];
            window[x] = function() {
                console.log(x);
                ox.apply(null,arguments);
            };
        })(x);
    }
}
```

However, this would only work on global functions, not functions of objects or scoped functions. It's also kind of a nuke, so is a poor substitute for manually adding console logging to the specific functions you want to call.

Instead it would probably be better to insert a breakpoint in the code (using the browser's developer tools) and checking the call stack at that point.

Comment: nice, I could also use the same structure to loop through any object I wanted to do this for.  That is I could put your could in a function where window is just one argument you might pass it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this is not possible with JavaScript as it doesn't support runtime modification of function contents.

You could, however, make a backup of your scripts and do a search & replace to save some time on the editing part; modern editors support basic regular expressions to help you out.

Comment: Wrapping the function at runtime would do the job. The only problem is getting a list of all functions.

Comment: @ThiefMaster that's right, though Kolink found a nice way around that :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a flow control library like [Frame.js](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js) the you have a low level access to the most important functions in your application. Of course you would have to build the application with Frame from the beginning. This won't work if you are trying to modify an already built application.