# How to know the changed property of an object using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
app.controller('indexController', ['$scope', 'authService', function ($scope, authService) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.$onInit = function () {
        vm.active = {
            "home": true,
            "welcome": false,
            "user": false,
            "logout": false,
            "login": false,
            "signup":false
        };
    };

    $scope.$watch('vm.active', function (newObj, oldObj) {
        // How to detect which property has changed ?
    }, true);

}]);
```

This way i tried, but i don't know how can i detect in watch(shown in my example code), which property has changed.

Comment: You want an object differ?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes. Say, if i make user = true then i want "user" property.

Comment: Why do you need to know which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run on the keys of one of the object, and filter it by the value.
Something like that:

```
const obj1 ={
    "home": true,
    "welcome": false,
    "user": false,
    "logout": false,
    "login": false,
    "signup":false
};

const obj2 = {
    "home": true,
    "welcome": false,
    "user": false,
    "logout": true,
    "login": true,
    "signup":false
};

const diff = Object.keys(obj1).filter((key) => obj1[key] !== obj2[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj1 ={
    "home": true,
    "welcome": false,
    "user": false,
    "logout": false,
    "login": false,
    "signup":false
};

const obj2 = {
    "home": true,
    "welcome": false,
    "user": false,
    "logout": true,
    "login": true,
    "signup":false,
    "somethingNew": false
};


for (myProperty in obj2){
    if (obj2[myProperty] !== obj1[myProperty]){
        alert(myProperty + ' has changed!');
    }
}
```

I believe this should do the trick using a for...in loop.

Answer (score 0):

i think watcher can't detect and property that's changed ,
you can make trick solution by using watchGroup or watchCollection 
( see $watchCollection will shallow watch the properties on a single object and notify you if one of them changes.

$watchGroup however watches a group of individual watch expressions.)

also you can check ( [how to know which object property changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789949/how-to-know-which-object-property-changed) ).