# Is it possible to watch object creation over the V8 debugging protocol?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

When creating an object in JavaScript via a user-defined constructor, it's easy enough to "hook" (e.g. do something before or after) the creation of the object at *runtime* as the constructor is just a function. In fact, [multiple Aspect Oriented Programming libraries exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005486/javascript-aop-libraries) to provide this functionality.

However, when using the [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals) notation, the object seems to be automagically created by the runtime. **Can the creation of these objects, or any other object in fact, be watched via the debugging protocol of V8?**

My motivation here is to be able to trace data flow in an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no, object literal instantiation cannot be watched.